Representation and the corresponding spectral measure
I'm reading a chapter about the relation between Hilbert space and quantum mechanics and got stuck at unclear correspondence.
Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space, $V$ be $\mathbb{R^{1,d-1}}$ and $U$ be a unitary representation of the vector group $V$ in $\mathcal{H}$
He defines positivity as

The representation of $U$ is called $positive$ if the support of the corresponding spectral measure lies in $\overline {V_+}$.

(here $\overline {V_+}$ is a subset of $V$)
I'm physicist, so, I'm not familiar with unclear relations even which is clear for mathematician.
Could you give me the relation between spectral measure and unitary representation?
Thanks for reading.

As stated, this makes no sense. If you have a unitary representation of an abelian locally compact group $G$, one can reasonably talk about the spectral measure, but it is defined on the Pontryagin dual group $\hat{G}$ instead of $G$, so saying the support lies within a subset of $V$ in your case doesn’t make any sense. Do you mind adding more context to this so that we may see what the author actually meant?

@DavidGao thanks for advising! I just added the picture of the page.

Ah, now it makes sense. So what exactly is the explanation you are seeking? How to obtain a spectral measure for a unitary representation $U: V \to \text{Aut}(H)$?

@DavidGao yes! I am not sure how to obtain spectral measure for the unitary representation.

And, could you understand  what $\mu_m$ is? I didn't understand the meaning of $Res\vert_{\mathcal O^+_m}$ and why it is possible to use $\frac{dv}{v^2-m^2}$ where the denominator is $0$. If you have any idea about that, could you share me?

I wrote an answer dealing with the main question. As for what $\mu_m$ is, I have no idea. I haven’t seen the notation $\text{Res}|_{\mathcal{O}_m^+}$ either. Perhaps it is a geometric notation? But I’m not a geometer.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This can be generalized to any unitary representation of a locally compact abelian group $G$ - such a representation always induces a spectral measure on the Pontryagin dual group $\hat{G}$. For the sake of simplicity, we’ll just focus on the case $V = \mathbb{R}^{1, d-1}$. The main observation here is that $V$ is its own dual, via Fourier transform:
$$\mathcal{F}(f)(p) = \int_V e^{-i(p,v)}f(v) \, dv$$
whose inverse is,
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)(v) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^d} \int_V e^{i(p,v)}g(p) \, dp$$
The main fact regarding the Fourier transform is that it changes convolution into multiplication, i.e., $\mathcal{F}(f \ast g) = \mathcal{F}(f)\mathcal{F}(g)$. This fact can be found, for example, in this Wikipedia article. Here, we recall that convolution is defined by,
$$(f \ast g)(v) = \int_V f(w)g(v-w) \, dw$$
As such, the inverse Fourier transform changes multiplication into convolution, i.e., $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(fg) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f) \ast \mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)$.
There is also a natural adjoint operation $^\dagger$ defined on the space of (suitable) functions by,
$$f^\dagger(v) = \overline{f(-v)}$$
where the line above indicates complex conjugation. One may easily check the following:
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\overline{g}) = (\mathcal{F}^{—1}(g))^\dagger$$
Now, a unitary representation $U: V \to \text{Aut}(H)$ induces a map $U’: L^1(V) \to L(H)$. (Here, $L^1(V)$ is the space of all integrable functions on $V$ - if you don’t know what that is, doesn’t matter, just pretend it is the space of all functions which make sense to integrate. $L(H)$ is the space of all bounded linear operators on $H$ - again, if you don’t know what that is, just pretend it consists of most “reasonable” linear operators from $H$ to itself, in particular all operators in $\text{Aut}(H)$, and you can integrate a function with values in $L(H)$.) $U’$ is simply defined by,
$$U’(f) = \int_V f(v)U(v) \, dv$$
I’ll let you check the following:
$$U’(f \ast g) = U’(f)U’(g)$$
$$U’(f^\dagger) = U’(f)^\dagger$$
(For the first equation, the main observation is that $U(v) = U(w)U(v - w)$ for all $v, w \in V$. For the second equation, the main observation is that $U(v)^\dagger = U(v)^{-1} = U(-v)$ for all $v \in V$.) We now combine $U’$ with the inverse Fourier transform:
$$\phi(f) = U’(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f))$$
Then $\phi$ is a linear map with the following properties:
$$\phi(fg) = U’(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(fg)) = U’(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f) \ast \mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)) = U’(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f))U’(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)) = \phi(f)\phi(g)$$
$$\phi(\overline{f}) = U’(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\overline{f})) = U’(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)^\dagger) = U’(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f))^\dagger = \phi(f)^\dagger$$
For any Borel subset $E$ of $V$, in particular, we may define,
$$\pi(E) = \phi(1_E)$$
where $1_E$ is the indicator function of $E$, i.e., the function that takes value $1$ on $E$ and $0$ everywhere else. Since $1_E = 1_E1_E$ and $1_E = \overline{1_E}$, we have, by the properties of $\phi$, that $\pi(E) = \pi(E)^2$ and $\pi(E) = \pi(E)^\dagger$, i.e., $\pi(E)$ are orthogonal projections, as required. We also have,
$$\pi(\varnothing) = \phi(1_\varnothing) = \phi(0) = 0$$
$$\pi(V) = \phi(1) = U’(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(1)) = U’(\delta_0) = U(0) = \text{Id}_H$$
where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac delta at $v = 0$. Moreover, if $E_1, E_2, \cdots$ are disjoint and $E = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j$, then $1_E = \sum_{j=1}^\infty 1_{E_j}$, so,
$$\pi(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j) = \phi(1_E) = \phi(\sum_{j=1}^\infty 1_{E_j}) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \phi(1_{E_j}) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \pi(E_j)$$
Finally, as $1_{E_1 \cap E_2} = 1_{E_1}1_{E_2}$, we have,
$$\pi(E_1 \cap E_2) = \phi(1_{E_1 \cap E_2}) = \phi(1_{E_1}1_{E_2}) = \phi(1_{E_1})\phi(1_{E_2}) = \pi(E_1)\pi(E_2)$$
So $\pi$ defines a spectral measure, as desired.
Remark: I’m doing this in an informal way, ignoring all sorts of issues with continuity and such. This can be done more formally, but I don’t think that is truly necessary for the purpose of doing physics.

Thanks!!!! Your explanation is perfect! The exercises are also helped me understand! I could never have understood without your help!!  Thank you very much!!
